# Cannot SSH in as root using Key

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, ssh-keys, root

I have searched through serverFault and cannot rectify my problem.

*An explanation:*

Ubuntu 14.04 - I am able to SSH into the server using user amenczykowski with a key. I am unable to SSH into the server as root.

I have checked that /root/.ssh/ has 700 privelidges set and that /root/.ssh/authorized_keys is set to 600. root:root is the owner for directory and file

Here is the contents of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
## Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 1222
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password

StrictModes yes
AllowGroups sshusers forge

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.    ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes


# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

I have restarted ssh by typing `$ service ssh restart`

The output for attempting to SSH into the server as root is:

```
Warning: Identity file /Users/adammenczykowski/ssh/isfirawebassoc not accessible:     No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 109.169.36.239 [109.169.36.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1     Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 03:7a:68:d9:25:10:b0:c4:aa:87:97:3f:95:e3:30:0d
debug1: Host '109.169.36.239' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/known_hosts:23
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: AdamPrivKey.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/fira
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/adammenczykowski/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the logs on your server say ?

Comment: Nov 11 19:06:46 graceful-flowers sshd[14039]: User root from 97e353ea.skybroadband.com not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following into /etc/ssh/sshd_config fixed it:

```
AllowGroups root sshusers forge
```